# CSS Height 100% without position absolute

Tags: html, css, height, absolute

Im displaying 3 div boxes in one row, but i want them to have a height on 100%. When im using position absolute and height 100%. The Box gets then to 100%, but they stack on each other. But i want them next to each other.

Comment: 100% height of what? The parent element? The viewport?

Comment: @InvolveX You can create a demo using a tool like http://codepen.io/pen/ to help illustrate your issue

Comment: of container... obviously.. to fill the explorer (for example)... question is so clear. For me.

Answer (score 2):

To make div's to have 100% height, you have to set body and html height also as 100%.

Instead you can consider using viewport widths. To make them side-by-side consider using display:flex.

check the following snippet

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width:60vw;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background: pink;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'd like to add that any percentage height element needs its parent element to have a height set or it doesn't work. This means that if your percentage height element isn't a child of `body` then setting `height: 100%;` on `html` and `body` won't work.